# Wordpress - ACF - Gatsby GraphQL - cannot get data from option pages in graphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I`m trying to get data from the ACF options pages. But every query is empty.
Here are my settings,

Fields are on and data should be visible somewhere:

[image: Settings]

[[image: Plugins2]

[image: GraphQl]

Question: Where I can find that kind of data related to the ACF options page named Theme Options in this case?

Comment: Can you share your plugin configuration?

Comment: explore WP graphql playground first (gatsby playground later) - there is a possibility that options are visible to admins only [or at least authed user]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for future searchers:

First You need to add ACF fields to graphql, when registering with acf_add_options_page:

```
'show_in_graphql' => true
```

Secondly, pick a location for your fields in ACF:

[image]

Then you should be able to find those fields in graphql (restart gatsby if needed).